# elementary differential equation(matrix)

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have

$$x'=Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -3 & -2 \\ 8 & -5 & -4\\ -4 & 3 & 3\end{bmatrix}x$$

where $1$ is a triple eigenvalue of $A$. I have solved similar problems that have a triple eigenvalue having only one eigenvector. For example,

$$x'=Ax=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & -1\\ -3 & 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}x$$

but the first problem has a triple eigenvalue having $2$ eigenvectors.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: oh sorry , have a general solution

Comment: You have the Jordan decomposition, right?

Comment: umm i dont learn that... perhaps the Jordan d' is needed??

Answer (score 0):

In the present case, you can easily find a Jordan basis by hand as follows.

The equation of the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $1$ is $\;4x-3x-2z=0$.

Note $(A-I)^2=0$, hence $\ker(A-I)^2=\mathbf R^3$. So take a first vector $e_3\in\mathbf R^3\setminus\ker(A-I)$, e.g. $e_3=(0,0,1)$, and set 
$$ e_2=(A-I)(e_2)=(-2,-4,2). $$
As $e_3\in\ker(A-I)^2$, $e_2\in \ker(A-I)$. Complete this set of vectors by a second eigenvector $e_1$, linearly independent from $e_2$, e.g
$\;e_1=(1,0,2).$

In basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, the matrix $A$ becomes, by construction,
$$A'=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}=I+N, \enspace\text{where}\enspace N=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\enspace\text{satisfies}\enspace N^2=0.$$

We have to calculate $\;\exp(A't)=\exp (It)\exp(Nt)$:
$$\exp(It)\exp(Nt) =(\mathrm e^t I)(It+Nt)=\begin{bmatrix}
t\mathrm e^t&0&0\\0&t\mathrm e^t&t\mathrm e^t\\0&0&t\mathrm e^t
\end{bmatrix} $$
From this, you deduce $\exp(At)$ from the change of basis formula.